# HTC One won't stop vibrating!

Tags: settings, htc

I need help trying to turn off the vibration on my HTC One.

I have done a ton of research, called customer support, and asked questions of people familiar with cell phones, and nothing has worked:

- I went to "Sound & Notification" and unchecked "Vibrate" and "Vibrate on Touch".
- Then I went to "Accessibility" and made sure "Notification Reminder" was off (it was).
- I even turned off the feature that sends notifications to my screen, and that didn't work either.

Everything everyone suggests isn't working and my phone keeps vibrating when notifications come in (not just for games or Facebook, but even for missed calls or voice messages and text messages). It's really loud when it vibrates because it reverberates through whatever it's leaning against, such as my desk or purse.

I have to put my phone on silent to avoid the vibrating, otherwise it can be heard in the next room.

I'd like to have it on a really low volume so I'm the only one who can hear it when it's sitting beside me at work, but the vibrating makes that impossible.

How do I get it to stop vibrating when all the settings for that feature are turned off?

Comment: Which Android version are you using? Go to Settings app -> About, if you don't know it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Weird that none of those settings worked. I would recommend **lowering the vibration intensity**, since it is a stock option on most HTC One devices now.

> Go to `Settings – Sound – Vibration intensity`. Then slide the bars
>   left or right to change the intensity.

Referenced [here](http://www.phonetipsandtricks.com/tips/htc-one/change-vibration-intensity-32/)

Other places to check: `Settings - Sound & notification - Other sounds - Vibration intensity`

If your device does not have that option, I have used **FauxClock on my HTC One M7** to adjust it via root: [Faux123 Kernel Enhancement - Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamkang.fauxclock&hl=en)

[image: FauxClock]

**If you have the M8, ElementalX Kernel** is a good option: [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2705613) It has vibration intensity controls, along with a load of other tweaks for saving battery, improving performance, etc.

If you're a fan of Xposed framework, there is an **[Xposed module](http://www.xda-developers.com/switch-your-phone-vibration-settings-with-xposed/)** available, but I'm not sure of the device compatibility.

If you **don't want to root at all**, there is an app called **Vybe that records custom vibration patterns** without root, see a description [here](http://www.xda-developers.com/vybe-generates-your-own-customized-vibrations/). You'd likely be able to record an "empty" vibration pattern so that your phone doesn't vibrate at all. Can't find it on Google Play, here's another app that has the same function, with good reviews: [Vibration Control - Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wbouvy.vibrationcontrol)

Hope one of these suits your needs